# Content-Security-Policy Header in Angular

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, azure

In angular application what are the values required for allowing in Content-Security-Policy header?
It throws me an error like this I've also added the web.config file in my angular application.

Here, I've also attached the index.html file.

[image: index html file]

[image: Content-security-policy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my end, I've found 2 solutions for the above item.

1.this is web.config file.

```
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer" />
    <add name="Permissions-Policy" value="camera=*,geolocation=*,microphone=*,autoplay=*,fullscreen=*,picture-in-picture=*,sync-xhr=*,encrypted-media=*,oversized-images=*" />
    <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    <add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
          style-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
          img-src https: data:;
          font-src https: data:;" />
  </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

and only for Content-Security-Policy header here is it

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://code.jquery.com https://cdnjs.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com; 
          style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com https://use.fontawesome.com;
          object-src 'none';
          img-src 'self' data: blob:;
          font-src 'self' data: https://use.fontawesome.com fonts.gstatic.com fonts.googleapis.com ;"
```

For every API call, if you need to add the below headers, you can add the headers in the http-interceptor file like this.

```
 req = req.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    "Permissions-Policy": "camera=*,geolocation=*,microphone=*,autoplay=*,fullscreen=*,picture-in-picture=*,sync-xhr=*,encrypted-media=*,oversized-images=*",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains",
    "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Xss-Protection": "1; mode=block",
    "Content-Security-Policy": "script-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';style-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';img-src https: data:;font-src https: data:;"
  }
});
```

Comment: Adding `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` defeats the purpose of CSP.