# Angular: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: javascript, angular, security, content-security-policy, unsafe-eval

In my application a blob fetched by means of a API-call is passed on to a custom npm-package that will show the blob on the screen (it’s an image). Locally it works! Only not on the development server.

```
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.example.com 'unsafe-inline' https://www.anotherexample.com".
```

A plane application has be made that fetches the blob and uses the same custom npm-package. The problem seem to be with Angular or better said with my settings. The settings locally are the same and its not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Basically its around XSS & security... Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67818124/content-security-policy-header-in-angular ... Things a a bit more lenient when serving locally.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not originated in Angular, the problem is your Content-Security-Policy (CSP). Your CSP is either defined in the `index.html` file as a `meta` tag in the `header` section, or set as a header on your server.

You could simply add 'unsafe-eval' to the CSP, but this is very risky in terms of security. To me, it seems like the library you are using here uses `eval` at some place, which is bad and should be avoided.

With development server, do you mean it is actually deployed, or the local server that starts with `ng serve`?

Comment: actually developed

Comment: whole point of implementing SCP is preventing unsafe eval